# Resolved: Positioning Scrollable Canvas In Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to update the current status of this problem.

While perhaps not the most efficient way of doing it, I have managed to create a canvas that scrolls through cards with the following program in Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.config(bg="green")
MainWindow.geometry("1350x680")
MainWindow.title("Canasta")


class Card:
    def __init__(self, cardText):
        self.__cardText = cardText
        self.__cardImage = ResizeCard(f"CardImages/{cardText}.png")

    def GetCardText(self):
        return self.__cardText

    def GetCardImage(self):
        return self.__cardImage


def ResizeCard(cardImage):
    cardInDeckImg = Image.open(cardImage)

    cardInDeckResizedImg = cardInDeckImg.resize((120, 200))

    # Output the card.
    cardInDeckImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cardInDeckResizedImg)

    return cardInDeckImg


def DisplayMeld(Meld, rowNo, meldNo, verticalPos, MeldFrame):
    if len(Meld) > 0:
        columnNo = 0

        Label(MeldFrame, text=f"{meldNo}. ", font=(
            'Helvetica 16 bold'), bg="green").place(x=horizontalPos, y=verticalPos)

        firstColumnFilled = False
        noOfCardsInRow = 0

        for card in Meld:
            if firstColumnFilled == False:
                Label(MeldFrame, text="                                                                                                                     ", bg="green").grid(
                    row=rowNo, column=columnNo)
                firstColumnFilled = True
            columnNo += 1

            if noOfCardsInRow == 5:
                rowNo += 1
                columnNo = 1
                verticalPos += 215
                noOfCardsInRow = 0

            Label(MeldFrame, image=card.GetCardImage()).grid(
                row=rowNo, column=columnNo, padx=(10, 0), pady=(0, 10))

            noOfCardsInRow += 1
            # Label(MeldFrame, image=card.GetCardImage()).pack(
            #     padx=(10, 0), pady=(0, 10), side=LEFT)

        rowNoAndVerticalPos = [rowNo, verticalPos]
        return rowNoAndVerticalPos


card1 = Card("AS")
card2 = Card("AS")
card3 = Card("AD")

redThree = Card("3H")

RoundFrame = Frame(MainWindow, bg="green")
RoundFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

canvas = Canvas(RoundFrame, bg="green")

# sticky='nsew' means occupy all available space in all directions.
# canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

scrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(RoundFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(
    scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

MeldFrame = Frame(canvas, bg="green")

# anchor="nw" means anchor the canvas to the top left corner.
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=MeldFrame, anchor="nw")

# Top card of stock pile GUI.
stockPileCoverImg = ResizeCard(f'CardImages/stockPileCover.png')

Label(RoundFrame, image=stockPileCoverImg).place(x=10, y=10)
Label(RoundFrame, text="Stock Pile", font=('Helvetica 16 bold'),
      bg="green").place(x=15, y=215)

# Top card of discard pile GUI.
topCardOfDiscardPile = Card("7D")

Label(RoundFrame, image=topCardOfDiscardPile.GetCardImage()).place(x=1203, y=10)
Label(RoundFrame, text="Discard Pile", font=('Helvetica 16 bold'),
      bg="green").place(x=1201, y=215)

Meld1 = [card1, card2, card3, card1, card2,
         card3, card1, card2, card3, card1, card2]
Meld2 = [redThree]

Melds = [Meld1, Meld2]

Label(MeldFrame, text="The following are your melds:", font=(
    'Helvetica 18 bold'), bg="green").place(x=505, y=15)
Label(MeldFrame, text="                            ",
      bg="green").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(0, 40))

rowNo = 1
horizontalPos = 445
verticalPos = 62
meldNo = 1
for Meld in Melds:
    rowNoAndVerticalPos = DisplayMeld(
        Meld, rowNo, meldNo, verticalPos, MeldFrame)
    returnedRowNo = rowNoAndVerticalPos[0]
    returnedVerticalPos = rowNoAndVerticalPos[1]

    rowNo = returnedRowNo + 1
    verticalPos = returnedVerticalPos + 215
    meldNo += 1

MainWindow.mainloop()
```

The following is what is outputted by the program:
[Program Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K63Gp.png)

I would like to thank everyone who assisted me along the way. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

To position the Stock and Discard Pile cards to be raised to 10 pixels below the top of the window:

```
Label(RoundFrame, image=stockPileCoverImg).grid(row=0,
                                                padx=(10, 1210), pady=(10, 0))
tkinter.Label(RoundFrame, text="Stock Pile", font=('Helvetica 16 bold'), bg="green").grid(row=1,
                                                                                  padx=(0, 1210), pady=(60, 0))

topCardOfDiscardPile = Card("7D")
Label(RoundFrame, image=topCardOfDiscardPile.GetCardImage()).grid(
    row=0, padx=(1210, 10), pady=(10, 0))
tkinter.Label(RoundFrame, text="Discard Pile", font=('Helvetica 16 bold'), bg="green").grid(row=1,
                                                                                    padx=(1210, 0), pady=(60, 0))
```

I recommend using `Label.place()` method to Aces displayed in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a grid manager but you don't use it's features.
The grid manager will do the coarse of your objects on a grid.
I don't know Canasta but I would use one column per deck. Column 0 may be your StockPile, your last column would be scrollbar and the previous would be Meld. Between columns 0 Stock and Meld would be your other decks.
Actually, your Canvas is in cell (0,0) and your StockPile is in cell(0,0). So your stockPile is on  top of your first Ace. Move your aces in columns 1,2 and 3 and you won't have conflicts.
If you absolutely want to use x,y coordinates, you should use 'place manager'.

Comment: Would it be easier if I used pack() instead of grid()?

Comment: No. You should use 'grid' or 'place'. I cannot recommend one since I don't know Canasta. Do you have a sketch to show how it looks with all decks in place?